# Django on Mac with mysql

Tags: python, mysql, django

I’m new in Django on Mac. I faced a problem in configuring Django environment with mysql on Mac.

The error is “

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: dlopen(/Users/david/david-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_mysql.so, 2): Symbol not found: _mysql_shutdown
Referenced from: /Users/david/david-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_mysql.so
Expected in: flat namespace
in /Users/david/david-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_mysql.so
```

”
I have referred serval related answers and methods from stackoverflow, such as

```
pip uninstall MySQL-python
brew uninstall mysql
brew install mysql --universal
pip install MySQL-python
```

Unfortunately, it doesn’t work.

I have built my virtualenv of python2.7.10 on Mac. I have used “pip install ” command to install serval packages including “Django-1.10.6”, “MySQL-python-1.2.5” and “mysqlclient”. 
I have installed “MySQL Server 5.7.17”, “MySQL Workbench” and “XCode”.  Everything looks good , but the error can not be fixed.

I also tried to use different versions of “MySQL-python” package, including “1.2.5” and “1.2.3” (I failed to install version 1.2.4). Failed either.

I hope there is someone could help give a hand and lead me out of the trouble which destroyed my weekend. Thank you very much.

Comment: I know this doesn't answer your question, but I would highly recommend *not* developing in your local macOS environment directly and instead use something like [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/) or [Docker](https://www.docker.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Downgrade your MySQL to 5.5 or below.

Refer to the [MySQL-python 1.2.5 intro page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/MySQL-python/1.2.5):

> MySQL-3.23 through 5.5 and Python-2.4 through 2.7 are currently
>   supported. Python-3.0 will be supported in a future release. PyPy is
>   supported.